# MYSQL Query CASE returning ELSE

Tags: mysql, sql

basically on the following lines where I have the two cases, it keeps returning the ELSES even though track_id is matched in the driver stats table for that driver_id as that is what I am grouping the query by. If I am doing this wrong, then what I need is if there are no rows in the driver_stats table then it gets the value from the drivers table and the growth is set to 0. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Case s.value When track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) Then s.value Else  d.value End AS value,
Case s.growth When track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) Then s.growth Else 0 End AS growth,

**//FULL QUERY**
SELECT d.drivers_id, d.drivername, t.code,
Case s.value When track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) Then s.value Else  d.value End AS value,
Case s.growth When track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) Then s.growth Else 0 End AS growth,
SUM(IF(qual_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS poles,
SUM(IF(race_pos <= '3', 1,0)) AS podiums,
SUM(IF(race_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS victories,
COALESCE(SUM(overtakes),0) AS overtakes,
SUM(Case When s.track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) Then points Else 0 End) lastracepoints,
COALESCE(SUM(points),0) AS points
FROM drivers d
Left Join driver_stats s
On s.drivers_id = d.drivers_id
Left Join teams t
On t.team_id = d.team_id
Group By d.drivers_id
ORDER BY d.drivers_id
```

Just for knowledge the table driver_stats has a row for each driver_id and for each track_id.

Comment: The field that follows when should match the one after the case statements i.e `Case fieldname when fieldvalue of the fieldname`

Comment: I'm going to remove my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the value between case and when, you should only add the value, and not the comparison.
Else MySQL will compare s.value to true, and it will be always false.

You have two options:

```
Case When track_id = (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) Then s.value Else  d.value End AS value,
```

or

```
Case s.value When (SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats) Then s.value Else d.value End AS value,
```

Anyway, in mySQL the next query would be easier to read:

```
if(s.value=SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats, s.value, d.value) as value
```

Comment: Hey thanks bin the last option you stated the (s.value=SELECT MAX(track_id) The value and track_id do not equal, the track_id is a just a test that when there IS a row with track_id then select the s.value.

Comment: Like this? `if((SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats)>0, s.value, d.value) as value`

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. If you just want to get the related d.value when it exists, can't you use `ifNull(d.value, s.value)`?

Comment: ok basically I want it to select the s.value when the s.track_id = the MAX track_id in the table, and if there are no rows then d.value.

Comment: What do you mean with "if there are no rows"? What if there are rows but the highest track_id is just not s.track_id?
Comparing the s.track_id would look like this:
`if((SELECT MAX(track_id) FROM driver_stats)=s.track_id, s.value, d.value) as value`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify your existing query to the following:

```
SELECT drivers_id, 
       drivername, 
       code,
       coalesce(s_value, d_value) value,
       coalesce(growth, 0) growth,
       SUM(IF(qual_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS poles,
       SUM(IF(race_pos <= '3', 1,0)) AS podiums,
       SUM(IF(race_pos = '1', 1,0)) AS victories,
       COALESCE(SUM(overtakes),0) AS overtakes,
       points lastracepoints,
       COALESCE(SUM(points),0) AS points
from
(SELECT d.drivers_id, d.drivername, t.code, s.value s_value, d.value d_value, s.growth, s.qual_pos, s.race_pos, s.overtakes, s.points
 FROM drivers d
 Left Join driver_stats s On s.drivers_id = d.drivers_id
 Left Join teams t On t.team_id = d.team_id
 ORDER BY d.drivers_id, track_id desc) v
Group By d.drivers_id
```